# Disabling Voice Control, or at least muting it (iOS 10)

Tags: audio, settings, siri, ios, voice-control

I have an iPhone 6S recently updated to iOS 10.0.1.

Holding the Home button for about 1 second activates Voice Control, with a characteristic loud double beep.  This is very easy to activate accidentally, which is especially undesirable if I am trying to discreetly check my phone during a meeting or something.  It's also easy to accidentally push the button when the phone is in my pocket (and locked).

I have no interest in actually using Voice Control at all, and it's very important to me that my phone not make unwanted noise.

Is it possible to:

- Disable Voice Control entirely?
- Stop it from beeping when activated?  (It doesn't respect the hardware Mute switch.)
- Reduce the volume of the beep?  (It doesn't seem to respect the ringer volume.)
- Prevent Voice Control from activating when the phone is locked?  (I would also prefer that unauthorized people not be able to use its features.)

I saw [Disable voice control on iPhone 4s, ios7.1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124437/disable-voice-control-on-iphone-4s-ios7-1) which suggests turning on Siri.  Indeed, Siri has options to disable access on lock screen, and to turn off "voice feedback", making it silent.  But for privacy reasons I do not want to enable Siri.

Since that question relates to much older versions of hardware and software, I am hoping that something has changed since then.  (Also, unlike in that question, my Home button works fine physically.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 10.2.1 (maybe as early as 10.2), it is possible to disable Voice Control.

```
Settings > General > Accessibility > Home Button
```

There is a setting `PRESS AND HOLD TO SPEAK`.  Set this to `Off`.  The descriptive text is "There will be no response when you press and hold the Home button."

I would like to thank [Bob Briscoe](http://stackexchange.com/users/6123914/bob-briscoe) for providing this answer, which he received from Apple Support. Since the question is protected, he cannot post an answer himself, so I am posting on his behalf.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way to disable it under iOS 10.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why the answer you're providing is better than others out there.  Having links can also help the OP, and others, evaluate your answer themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: So very sad! They should fix this user-hostile interface.

Comment: As of iOS 10.2.1 this is no longer true; see [other answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270828/120743).

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible work-around. I haven't tried it myself, but here are the steps:

1. Under Settings > Siri, enable Siri (temporarily; you will be disabling it again later).
2. Under Settings > Touch ID & Passcode (or simply Passcode for devices prior to iPhone 6), turn on SIRI (again) on this screen, a new option should have appeared called Voice Dial. Disable it.
3. Go back into Settings > Siri and disable Siri again.

Comment: After enabling Siri, there was no Voice Dial option under Touch ID & Passcode.

Comment: Do you have a passcode set? If not, you'll need to set one to cause the option to appear.

Comment: Yes, I do have a passcode set.  Oh, on further inspection, it appears that the Voice Dial switch only appears when Siri is *dis*abled.  It is switched off.  Doesn't help.

Comment: Odd, because I have Siri enabled and Voice Dial appears for me. In any event, after further research, this (was) in fact Apple's solution for disabling it. It may be that you can no longer disable it in iOS 10 despite the presence of that option.

Comment: Were you testing with iOS 10?

Comment: Yes, though as I said I didn't try actually disabling Siri and seeing what happened. I just know that the option is present in my settings.

Comment: On your newly upgraded ios10 device, with Siri enabled, Voice Dial appears under Passcode. You then switch it off. This has absolutely no effect whatsoever and the phone will still voice dial whenever it likes. Turn Siri off and make sure it's disabled on the home screen. Find out again that Voice Dial is still enabled and calling people without your knowledge. Google dejectedly for a while, then go onto better things and hope that ios 10.1 fixes this. It's just broken. Sorry.

Comment: Point is, you have to enable Siri in Touch ID and Passcode too, or the Voice Dial option won't show up there.

Comment: Also I don't think this method works fully for iOS 10 and possibly earlier. As soon as I disable Siri, voice control goes on by pressing home button down for a second in locked mode. I guess we will just have to keep Siri on? Well, I never needed or could successfully use Siri anyway so I hope I don't get into trouble with Siri for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the volume for it or mute it altogether.

When the voice control screen pops up, press on your iPhone's volume down key to the desired level.

Comment: I was able to lower the volume this way, but not to mute it (the volume decreased to one bar, but further presses of the volume down button don't do anything further).  But that's already a big improvement, so +1 from me.

Comment: If you were to mute it altogether, it's vibrate, which, to me, is equally annoying.  But, hey, all we can do is the best we can, no?

Answer (score -1):

You either have Siri on, but remove her access to the home screen, or you have voice control on the home screen. There are no currently options to disable both.

With Siri on but no access to the home screen you won't have the pinging, but you'll have to live knowing Siri knows everything about you. If you disable her, the voice control ping comes back to the home screen. Hopefully Apple updates this garbage "update" soon.

Comment:   I guess first I'm bemused that you would dismiss a major OS upgrade as garbage over one (what appears to be a) bug. Second, Siri doesn't know anything about you *unless you use it*. Just because it's enabled doesn't mean you are required to use it.